# Infinite expansion of non-linear expressions with 3 or more variables

Tags: infinity

I just realised that if we expand any of the non-linear expression with power of 3 or more we can't stop expanding them until we are dead.

So for example:

**Expansion:**
$(a+b+c)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2ab + 2bc + 2ac$

**Grouping:**
$(a+b+c)^2 = \textbf{(a + b + c)}^{\textbf 2} + 2(ab+ bc + ac)$

The bold part in the very above equation has an expression that can be again expanded to $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2ab + 2bc + 2ac$ and so that will go on forever.

Can anyone tell me if I am wrong anywhere or is this true?

Comment: uh $(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+ac+bc)$.  $$(a+b+c)^3=a^3+b^3+c^3+3(ab^2+a^2b+ac^2+a^2c+bc^2+b^2c)+6abc$$

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: what do you mean by "grouping?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an important principle in algebra, that the order of operations must be observed.

$$(a+b+c)^2$$

requires you to perform the additions first, followed by the squaring operation.

$$a^2+b^2+c^2$$

requires you to perform the squarings first, and then the additions. You cannot switch between them, generally. To demonstrate why this is true, notice that

$$
1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 = 14 \neq 36 = (1+2+3)^2
$$
And so, even with this simple example, you can see that $a^2+b^2+c^2\neq(a+b+c)^2$.

Grouping involves recognition of where an operation distributes over another operation. $ab+ac = a(b+c)$. This works because multiplication distributes over addition. However, the squaring operation does not distribute over addition - instead, it distributes over multiplication. So $(ab)^2 = a^2b^2$. But $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2\neq a^2+b^2$ (unless $2ab=0$, which only happens when $a=0$ or $b=0$).

Your expression for $(a+b+c)^3$ is also in error, the right hand side is the expansion of $(a+b+c)^2$. But I suspect that is a typo.

Comment: I said that the (a+b+c)^2 = (a+b+c)^2 + **2(a+b+c)**. And so that gives us the right thing :)

Comment: But $(a+b+c)^2\neq (a+b+c)^2+2(ab+ac+bc)$. Instead, $(a+b+c)^2 = a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+ac+bc)$.

Comment: Also, notice the extra bit I just edited in. It might clarify things for you.